# How to upgrade Django in visual studio

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

Is there any method to upgrade the Django and project to the latest version?

Thanks,
Saeed

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall the current version by

```
pip uninstall Django
```

Then install the newer version

```
pip install Django==2.1.4
```

Note that: latest Django version worked with python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 version. Your older version code has backward compatibility, breaks somewhere. If you still need to upgrade version of Django, be sure to that.

Comment: Should I write this commands in Django shell in visual studio?

Comment: yes. Also check python version.

Comment: I write this command in Windows PowerShell but nothing happens in the visual studio. Django shell in visual studio doesn't accept this command and errors: syntax error. Can you please describe more where should I write?

Comment: https://djangobook.com/developing-django-visual-studio/ see this